# How to filter queryset for foreign key that is inherited

Tags: django, inheritance, foreign-keys, django-queryset

I have a class `A`:

```
class A(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

class `B` that has a foreign key of class `A`:

```
class B(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

then I have class `C` that is inherited from class `B`:

```
class C(B):
    class Meta:
        managed = True
    text = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Is class `C` also has foreign key of class `A`. If it has, how can I get class `A` objects that satisfies certain requirements of object of class `C`.
I tried to do something like:
    `A.objects.filter(c_text='Hello')`
But it doesn't work. I can't even get right filter with Pycharm tips.

Comment: How does this inherit from `B`? Note that it is usually not a good idea to do extensive subclassing.

Comment: Sorry, I edited my question.